# swipe between activities,swipe from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-animation, swipe, swipe-gesture

I am trying to do swipe activity but failed to do so. Below will be my code but its doing nothing, not even giving any error. I don't know what to do.

```
    final View lay_first=(View) findViewById(R.id.lay_first);

    lay_first.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onSwipeLeft() {
            Intent intent=new Intent(SlideWindow.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left, R.anim.rl2);
                return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSwipeRight() {
        Intent intent=new Intent(SlideWindow.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_to_left, R.anim.rl2);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSwipeBottom() {
            super.onSwipeBottom();
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onSwipeTop() {
            super.onSwipeTop();
            return true;
        }
});
}
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener{       
     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    GestureDetector gestureDetector=new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {         
        if(gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener{
     private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
         private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;


         @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return super.onDown(e);
        }

         @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result=false;

        try
        {
            float diffY=e2.getY()-e1.getY();
            float diffX=e2.getX()-e1.getX();

            if(Math.abs(diffX)>Math.abs(diffY))
            {
      if(Math.abs(diffX)>SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX)>SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
                {
                    if(diffX>0)
                    {
                        result=onSwipeRight();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result=onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
            if(Math.abs(diffY)>SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY)>SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
                {
                    if(diffY>0)
                    {
                        result=onSwipeBottom();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result=onSwipeTop();
                    }       }
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return result;
        }   }
       public boolean onSwipeRight()
         {
    return false;
          }
         public boolean onSwipeLeft()
         {
    return false;                
         }
         public boolean onSwipeBottom() {
             return false;
     }
         public boolean onSwipeTop() {
             return false;
     }
}}
```

But when I am doing slide simply on touchevent it is running.But when I am adding the gestures it is not,as GestureDetector class is depriciated is this the reason for this program not running.

Comment: swipe action not performing??

Comment: Why don't you use viewpager with fragments ?

Comment: whats the point to implement this swipe to change activity? horizontal swipe with viewpagers doesnt work well?

Comment: I am trying to use view pager, and yes swipe action is not performing using GestureDetector.

Comment: if you have any example of how to use viewpager,please show me the link. And thank you.

Comment: if you are using any IDE (eclipse / android studio), create a new project. You will automatically get an option to crete view pager layout. Chose that option (pager with tabs) and start developing. android apidemos has examples though

Comment: I put it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, official tutorial
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Comment: sorry it is till not working,same thing type of output,swipe is not performing and neither giving any error.

Comment: take a look at this, it lso includes a source code which you use as a reference http://www.programmingmobile.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-viewpager.html